# Why does the second sentence use 个?

Tags: word-choice

I read this sentence today :

> 每天给自己的手机充电，
>   也不要忘了给自己的口语充个电！

I wonder why the second sentence use 个 between 充 and 电 while the first one doesn’t.

Could anyone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 2):

It’s vernacular language.

> Charge your phone every day, and don’t forget to also give your speaking [skills] **a** charge!

個 is a generic counter for an event or session in this case, and will commonly be heard in a casual spoken style.

You can get similar constructions e.g.

- 吃個飯 (have a meal)
- 旅個遊 (go on a travel)